# Next.js global redirect to lowercase URLs

Tags: next.js

It looks that by default Next.js handles URLs in a case-insensitive manner (at least when using [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites)).

I found [this documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) on `redirects` and was wondering if there is a way to do a global redirect if a URL is found with capital letters, to its equivalent lowercase letter URL?

Is there a way to do this either with redirects or some other way? (ideally looking for a global solution)

Here is a pseudo-code (non-functional) of what I had in mind (this would be in `next.config.js`):

```js
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:url*(\p{Alphabetic})',
        destination: `/${url.toLocaleLowerCase()}`,
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not appear that such feature exists, but ultimately this type of feature might be better resolved by fixing this issues documented here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/21498

There might be other reasons for more advanced URL manipulation and this might become a feature request at some point if the community needs this.